# Is there a way to prevent angular from redirecting #foo to #/foo?

Tags: angularjs

I'm migrating an app to AngularJS, I want to do it in a modular way, just parts by parts. For now, the URLs are not to be handled by Angular. But when I use `ng-include` angular automatically starts rewriting the URL, for no reason, since `ng-include` got nothing to do with the URL.

So I'm trying to use an Angular module in a page with the `website.com/#somethingAfterTheHash` URL, and when I use `ng-include`, the URL turns into `website.com/#/somethingAfterTheHash`. And the app breaks.

Is there a way to stop Angular? Or will be better off trying to stop the app from breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure angular not to use it like this: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`. Read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location). The hashtag is used for older (non-HTML5) browsers.

> To configure the $location service, retrieve the $locationProvider and set the parameters as follows:

```
html5Mode(mode): {boolean}
true - see HTML5 mode
false - see Hashbang mode
default: false
```

Comment: I know that, but I do want to use hashtags. What I don't want, however, is an additional slash after the hash, because that breaks the rest of the non-angular app.

Anyway, using HTML5 mode seems to prevent Angular from adding an additional slash to the hash, so I guess does solve the problem, although I won't be able to use hash URLs in the future, so I'm not sure if using this or not.

Comment: Hmmm, you want something in between... not sure it's possible. But, if you wish to use hashes in a regular, non-angular way, I think that's possible with html5 mode.